# NavigationView, нужно перейти с одного фрагмента на другой в боковом меню. как это сделать?

Tags: android-fragment, activity, android-navigation-drawer, fragment-transaction

перерыл кучу информации, за ранее благодарен за помощь.
Есть боковое меню(NaviagtionView), при нажатии кнопки "расписание" в меню - переходим во фрагмент расписание(Raspisanie.java).Мне нужно из фрагмента Расписание так же продолжить переход по клику еще в несколько разных фрагментов(факультет А, факультет И и т.д.). 
Как это сделать?

> **MainActivity.java**'

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.container, new Raspisanie()).commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Создадим новый фрагмент
    Fragment fragment = null;
    Class fragmentClass = null;

    // Handle navigation view item clicks here.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.nav_raspisanie) {
        fragmentClass = Raspisanie.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_calendar) {
        fragmentClass = HelpStudy.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_dosiePrepodov) {
        fragmentClass = DosiePrepodov.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_history) {
        fragmentClass = HistoryBSTU.class;
    } else if (id == R.id.nav_support) {

    } else if (id == R.id.nav_exit) {
    }

    try {
        fragment = (Fragment) fragmentClass.newInstance();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    // Вставляем фрагмент, заменяя текущий фрагмент
    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, fragment).commit();
    // Выделяем выбранный пункт меню в шторке
    item.setChecked(true);
    // Выводим выбранный пункт в заголовке
    setTitle(item.getTitle());

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);

    return true;
}
```

}

> **Raspisanie.java**

```
public class Raspisanie extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.raspisanie, container, false);
}
```

}

> **raspisanie.xml**

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/facultets"
    android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
    android:textSize="20dp"
    />

<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
    android:id="@+id/table_1"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/facultet_A"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="A"
        android:id="@+id/facultet_A"
        />
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/facultet_I"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="И"
        android:id="@+id/facultet_I"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/facultet_E"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="E"
        android:id="@+id/facultet_E"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/facultet_O"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="O"
        android:id="@+id/facultet_O"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/facultet_P"/>
    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="P"
        android:id="@+id/facultet_P"/>
</TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Решил проблему добавлением в `onViewCreated` фрагмента:

```
@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    view.findViewById(R.id.facultet_A).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container,
                    new Facultet_A()).addToBackStack(null).commit();

        }
});
```